# Where should I configure max_result_window index setting?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastica

I'm trying to add to my `elasticsearch.yml`

```
index.max_result_window: 10000
```

But the problem is it doesn't like me adding `index.` in the configuration (it results in an error), this was working in elastica version 2.X, but now in 6.X it doesn't seem to work. Any idea how to configure indexes in recent elastica versions? I can't seem to find an answer to this.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The `max_result_window` is a dynamic index level setting, not node specific.  The default is 10,000, so if that's the value you'd like to set, there should be no need.

You can adjust it by updating either a specific index settings or globally across all *existing* indices:

```
PUT _settings
{
  "index.max_result_window": 11000
}
```

The above would update all *existing* indices.  To have it take effect on future indices, you'd need an index template that targets specific index patterns (or just * for global) - as an example:

```
PUT _template/example
{
  "index_patterns": ["settings_test*"],
  "settings": {
    "index.max_result_window": 12000
  }
}

PUT settings_test
```

The above would yield the following:

```
GET settings_test
...

{
  "settings_test" : {
    "aliases" : { },
    "mappings" : { },
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        ...
        "max_result_window" : "12000",
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Ref: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules.html

Comment: Thanks for your response but per my tag I'm looking for an elastica solution.

Comment: Elastica is just a client for accessing the Elasticsearch cluster - you indicated you were trying to update your `elasticsearch.yml` file which has nothing to do with Elastica. The commands above can be done either as simple curl commands against the Elasticsearch cluster, or if you want to use Elastica, look at the `setSettings` method which will send the same info above to your Elasticsearch cluster. Ref: https://elastica.io/api/latest/classes/Elastica.Index.html#method_setSettings

Answer (score 0):

For elastica I think this is the solution:

```php
// Load index
$elasticaIndex = $elasticaClient->getIndex('twitter');

// Create the index new
$elasticaIndex->create(
    array(
        'number_of_shards' => 4,
        'number_of_replicas' => 1,
        'analysis' => array(
            'analyzer' => array(
                'default_index' => array(
                    'type' => 'custom',
                    'tokenizer' => 'standard',
                    'filter' => array('lowercase', 'mySnowball')
                ),
                'default_search' => array(
                    'type' => 'custom',
                    'tokenizer' => 'standard',
                    'filter' => array('standard', 'lowercase', 'mySnowball')
                )
            ),
            'filter' => array(
                'mySnowball' => array(
                    'type' => 'snowball',
                    'language' => 'German'
                )
            )
        ),
        'max_result_window' => 10000
    ),
    true
);
```