# rg.elasticsearch.search.query.QueryPhaseExecutionException: Result window is too large

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch

Caused by: org.elasticsearch.search.query.QueryPhaseExecutionException: Result window is too large, from + size must be less than or equal to: [10000] but was [2872980]. See the scroll api for a more efficient way to request large data sets. This limit can be set by changing the [index.max_result_window] index level settin

when data record more than 10000 records it show error empty response. i am try different solution but there was not solution is valid. solution like this
PUT bookings/_settings
{
"max_result_window" : 500000
}

PUT bookings/_settings
{
"index": {
"max_result_window": 100000000
}
}

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55594386/where-should-i-configure-max-result-window-index-setting/55596945#55596945).

Try the following:

[Image attached for more detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZuZP.png)

```
PUT bookings/_settings { "index.max_result_window": 100000000 }
```

Comment: please see image attached for issue

Comment: I can’t see the image??

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZuZP.png

Comment: all data  index in elastic search. more than document save 18000 near record.send request for get data from elastic search but in response show https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZuZP.png